# javascript not working in UIWebview's button onsubmit where as safari works fine?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am using `UIWebView` in my app with a load request of HTTP URL. Webpage loaded URL without fail but Which has the button with action as javascript. Problem is `onclick` of submit nothing happens and no error in console and `UIWebView` delegates also not fired, including error delegate. That Button just acts like image view. Whereas submit button `onclick` responded well in mobile safari app. Below I have attached partial view source code of my HTTP URL

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1"><link href="/App_Themes/Common.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Script/siteCommon.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    

<link href="../../App_Themes/default/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /><title>
    Change Password
</title></head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="10470" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="_TSM_HiddenField_" id="_TSM_HiddenField_" value="2GFwlGU9ATlFIxrdsXRzcja58_1t5F8HSleaZM4ZQwk1" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=0yNOlELC71f7MU1kDN0EjQ2&amp;t=635152212760076874" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=c93c_YnvR2d5xbofY3U48Vv2IRMVoKIPk_hrlJ8-C5LxDZb6nfS51RYyYBFDJDWwblnlsXZ0-KwhxpojwLpoQQ2&amp;t=1e961a8d" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=CBZ_3hbD_tfINaKqOHxpx7JALH5uYYEO3oWKa0RYfcnTbdSBTlY7W2hGWTKE5diJ0&amp;t=ffffffff81f1a403" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=CBZ_3hbD_tfINaKqOHxpx7JALH5uYYEO3oWKa0RYfcmlwqDqfxGdA2J9XRFKE5rz0&amp;t=ffffffff81f1a403" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/actions/password/10470?_TSM_CombinedScripts_=True&amp;v=2GFwlGU9ATlFIxrdsXRzcja58_1t5F8HSleaZM4ZQwk1&amp;_TSM_Bundles_=&amp;cdn=False" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=CBZ_3hbD_tfINaKqOHxpxwkS3UqxfzxcZj62hGX0hvK9oQFljrnoDHbkkd4RNQkVAwNoEXOsrlyOHfAU-XrwAw2&amp;t=ffffffff81f1a403" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=CBZ_3hbD_tfINaKqOHxpxyqbdySWicIlJxGXGKbjz5V_OOL5bgqUM-2ewmqJqIBS_FJCzNDx5yt8EYyx12l3wQ2&amp;t=ffffffff81f1a403" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function WebForm_OnSubmit() {
if (typeof(ValidatorOnSubmit) == "function" && ValidatorOnSubmit() == false) return false;
return true;
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: try with safari by `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webURL]];`.. and check it now. ;)

Comment: some errors in console? and there is only form, please add button code to question

Comment: @sage44: i have added few code from viewsource file for ur reference .i don't have any idea about html and javascript. so plz let me know if u want some more info

Comment: @iPatel : but i want that page in UIWebview.and i want to debug above issue and make it work

Comment: yea, I see updated code. when you click button `webView:shouldStartLoadRequest` calls?

Comment: @sage444:no it doesn't call any delegate . including webView:shouldStartLoadRequest

Comment: Please post your class.m file's code where you are assigning the webview and url.

Comment: You may want to test your file with https://validator.w3.org/check. It looks like the <form> tag is not closed. I don't think that would be a problem in UIWebView, but it couldn't hurt to fix it

Comment: It is possible that may be it is calling a ajax request on that button click. Because ajax request can be tracked by simple web view delegate.

Comment: Seems some javascript error.. Code looks fine.. can you check it with http://www.jslint.com..